# Using JTextField in a JApplet

Tags: java, swing, input, jframe, japplet

This is my first time messing with JApplet.. I'm trying to make this JTextField() work properly... But no matter what i do i cant get it to show up on the page!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hangman extends JApplet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3966472303224962681L;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        JTextField input = new JTextField(20);

        c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.drawString("Welcome to the Hagman Applet for the Web!", 20, 30);

        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 18));
        g.drawString("also available on android.", 20, 50);

        c.add(input);
        input.getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"This is my first time messing with JApplet."*   Do it the same way you might do it in a frame.  Then launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  Why code an applet? If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Thanks I'll talk to her about using a Jframe instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add components to your applet in the "paint" method. Do it f.e. in the constructor:

```
 public Hangman() {
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    c.add(input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for a tutorial on [JApplet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html) (link to javadoc).
It does not differ from a JFrame.

You can call `setLayout(...)` for a layout manager, or `setLayout(null)` for absolute positioning (where all components like JTextField need to be positioned).

You can add the components to `getContentPane()`.

There are four overridable life-time functions: `init, start, stop, destroy`. *(You probably overlooked them, as the are defined in the base class Applet.)* So for instance put all code in `start`. Forget about `paint`. (Repainting could happen periodically!)

Use a JLabel for the static text, maybe a JButton too.